# Interconnection between Discord and Desktop app

Tags: integration, discord

I'm using Discord for multiple communities. While that's great for its purpose, I would like people to use more a specific Desktop app and meet there instead.

An interconnection between Discord and the app would be advantageous. Something that just clicked on a Discord channel and instead of being a voice / text channel opened the app.

Is it possible to make such thing? If yes, how? If not, I'm interested to know about similar flows too.